# Sum over real photon polarizations. The minus sign

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, conventions

Ok for real photons there is the formula when summing over the polarizations:

$$ \sum_{\lambda=\pm}\epsilon^{*\mu}_\lambda\epsilon^\nu_\lambda = -\eta^{\mu\nu}$$

But if I have a matrix element of the form:
$$\epsilon^{*\mu}M_\mu\qquad \epsilon^\mu\bar{M}_\mu$$

So when I take the absoulte squared of that I have:
$$|M|^2 = \epsilon^{*\mu}M_\mu \epsilon^\nu\bar{M}_\nu= -M_\mu\eta^{\mu\nu}M_\nu = -M \bar{M}$$

But know the absolute squared is negative. So I know I have a heavy mistake somewhere here. Can someone help me understand?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are using the $(1,-1,-1,-1)$ signature right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I didn't mention.

Comment: Why must $M_\mu M^{*\mu}>0$?

Comment: Well I thought that now we have $|M|^2 = -M_\mu M^\mu$ and the total amplitude should be real of course and positive? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-M_\mu\eta^{\mu\nu}M_\nu=-M_0^2+M_1^2+M_2^2+M_3^2$$
Since due to Ward identity $M_0=M_3$ (choosing $x^3$ as the direction of motion), the above result is positive.

Comment: Seems logical. Since it should be positive and also in my actual calculations if I evaluate the resulting Trace I get something positive. I was just looking for a general explanation to see why this should be the case.